# Howto get content displayed in main section of html5 page using Bootstraps navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

after spending days of my life searching a solution for problem above I try to ask here my first question hoping somebody could help me.

I am a newbie using bootstrap 4.0 which is normal quite easy ;-) but I am also a newbie in Javascript, however I like to develop my first own webpage in HTML5 with a simple layout like
 - Header
 - Main
 - Footer

My decision was to use native Bootstrap no php, Typo3, Wordpress or anything else and I like DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). If necessary for the solution my sample problem below maybe JS, jquery, ajax ... could be used but if possible no solution like using php etc. And I would no switch back to nav-tabs.

The main problem I have is how could I get the content of a external html-file loaded into the main area of the index.html file depending in the navbar items ? Means if I click in the navbar on Blog I would like to load the content from html/blog.html same for Action 1..3

Please notice html import is also not possible because Firefox has no plans to support it

Here is the simple coding with modification used from a original bootstrap example

---

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>My Testpage</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<header>
  <!-- A header picture here -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<!--            <a class="nav-item active nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id="id_blog">Blog</a> -->
      <a class="nav-item active nav-link" href="#" id="home" data-src="html/home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id="blog" data-src="html/blog.html">Blog</a>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<!--                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="id_action1">Action1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="id_action2">Action2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="id_action3">Action3</a>
-->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="act1" data-src="html/act1.html">Action1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="act2" data-src="html/act2.html">Action2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="act3" data-src="html/act3.html">Action3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>

  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>My Testpage</h1>
      <section id="content">
        <!-- Content from other pages below html/ like loadpage.html should go in here -->
      </section>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer" id="footer">
    <!-- Some footer stuff here -->
  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  // Initial load of the home content refrehed after each user action on url reload page action
  $("#content").load("html/home.html");

  // Pages to Load on click on Navbar menu
  $("a").map( function(index, element) {
// console.log( index + " " + $(this).attr('id') + " " + $(this).attr('data-src') );
$(this).on("click", function() {
  if( $(this).attr('data-src') !== undefined ) {
    $("#content").load($(this).attr('data-src'));
  }
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Optional Solution, but more work, need to maintain each menu entry
<script>
  $("#home").on("click", loadContent);
  $("#blog").on("click", loadContent);
  $("#act1").on("click", loadContent);
  $("#act2").on("click", loadContent);
  $("#act3").on("click", loadContent);

  function loadContent(index, value){
$("#content").load($(this).attr('data-src'));
  };

</script>
-->

</body>

</html>
```

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi all, I found the solution by myself WITHOUT using IFRAMES nor oversized CMS.

Comment: So the only thing you'll need is jQuery

Answer (score 0):

did you want this? try to click the home,blog and dropdown buttons.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>My Testpage</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<header>
    <!-- A header picture here -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-item active nav-link" href="#" data-src="https://cn.bing.com/images/discover?form=Z9LH">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id="id_blog" data-src="https://www.bing.com/translator/">Blog</a>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-src="https://outlook.live.com/owa/?WT.mc_id=O16_BingHP?mkt=en-US">Action1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-src="https://cn.bing.com/videos/trending" id="id_action2">Action2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-src="https://www.office.com/?WT.mc_id=O16_BingHP">Action3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>My Testpage</h1>
            <section id="content">
                <!-- Content from other pages below html/ like loadpage.html should go in here -->
                <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1000px" seamless scrolling="no"></iframe>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
        <!-- Some footer stuff here -->
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        let frame = document.getElementById('iframe');
        let frameSrc = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-src]');
        frameSrc.forEach(function(ele) {
            ele.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-src'));
                frame.src = event.target.getAttribute('data-src');
            }, false);
        });
    };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes that is nearly what I am looking for, my "external resources" are local subpages for ex. means my personal blog.html file located in subfolder html/ only as explanation. Is there a possibility to get this work without the <iframe> tag, which may can result in security issues in a page ?

Comment: @Thorsten that is possible only with a little trouble without iframe.with iframe,you just need change the data-src.without iframe,you have to write more code.for example,you have to get the file by ajax,and add the content to the present html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate three complete different websites/ webapps into one webpage you either need to use iframes or search for a complete other solution.

Using iframes is possible so it has some drawbacks. and that should not be security. That can be secured, especially within the same domain. You even can change the size of the iframe from within the iframe (you need some JS to exchange information to the outer page), so even a window resizing could be responsive up to the iframe.
The drawbacks of iframes are: no deep-links and during a page change within the iframe the scroll position of the outer page stay the same (so you will not start at the top of the iframe/ the top of the new loaded page, which is very irritating for greater forms.

I would prefer other solutions: where you can integrate all your functionality into one CMS. This should be easier to configure, update, maintain.